# Passing multiple variables to an event listener

Tags: javascript, google-maps, event-handling, dom-events, google-maps-markers

I am working with the Google Maps API and multiple markers. On a marker, there needs to be a click event to open an info window. I got that part working. I was wondering if there was a way to pass multiple variables and add the same event listener on all those markers?

I currently have:

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                        _(that.popups).each(function (popup) {
                            popup.hide();
                        }).value();

                        infowindow.show(/*that.map, marker*/);
                    });
```

If I have a `nyMarker` variable, then a `laMarker` variable, how do I pass on this to the event handler?

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple; there are two methods as you want to do, both of them work; what you have to do is just use **forEach()** like this -

***#First Method***

1. Here first you have to add a new and same class to all your elements (or use the
   old one if you already have) and then access them using **querySelectorAll()**
   function.
2. Then you have to use **forEach()** to target all of them

```js
// accessing the elements with same classname using querySelectorAll() function
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.my-box');

// adding the event listener by looping
elements.forEach(element => {
   element.addEventListner('click', ()=>{
     console.log('action');
   });
});
```

***#SecondMethod***

1. First you have to initialize all the variables through **querySelector()** or **getElementsByClassName()[]** or how ever you want do so..

```js
const element1 = document.querySelector('.a');
const element2 = document.querySelector('.b');
const element3 = document.querySelector('.c');
```

2. Then you have to target them using **forEach()** like this -

```js
[element1, element2, element3].forEach((element)=>{
    element.addEventListner('click', ()=>{
      console.log('action');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just possible by adding them to **one result-set**. I would prefer using jQuery instead of plain javascript:

```
var elems = [$element1, $element2, $element3, ...];
var $result = $();

$.each(elems, function() {
    $result = $result.add(this);
});

$result.bind(...);
```

Multiple values are not working in this case `:)`

Hope this helps! Let me know if you got further questions!

Comment: I saw the answer for elements but my markers are not elements. they are variables that have data. I am not sure if this is the same logic.

Comment: Looks like I could't follow your thoughts the right way... `What do you mean with I was wondering if there was a way to pass multiple variables to an event listener because i have multiple different marker variables.`? `:)` @user3730179

Comment: my variable is not an element. an example is this https://jsfiddle.net/drmak3os/1/

Comment: >So then I'm pretty sure yo are able to use the variables if they are defined before the event listener. Don't you? @user3730179

Comment: @user3730179 so I can keep adding variables after the comma? so google.maps.event.addListener(marker, laMarker, nyMarker ....